# LTC 4150 coulomb counter property

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charging, discharge

I want to monitor the capacity of a 7.4V, 2200mAH Li-ion battery. I have found a that [LTC4150](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4150fc.pdf) coulomb counter can able to measure the battery capacity. So, suppose I have connected a fully charged battery and monitor the battery capacity. So, after draining the battery to a some amount, what value it will show through a controller, the remaining battery capacity or the amount of AH I have used? I think it will show the amount of battery capacity I have used as per as its calculation of coulomb charge formula given in datasheet. So, if it works like this, then how can I estimate the battery capacity if it is not fully charged? (if 70-90% charged is present and connecting to the load).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1Ah = 3600 • GVF • RSENSE Interrupts (8)

RSENSE= Imax* 50mV

Software can choose value for empty or full.

Using suitable up-down counter.  Initialize Count = 100% then count down with ratio to indicate capacity and count up to full .

Calibration check

Reinitialize after CC to CV to 10% CC cutoff = 100%

Cutoff use if capacity is <=10% or Vbat<=3V

But some calibration error checking is needed, something like...

- then if count down = 10% is reached but Vbat > 3.4 add count correction factor
- if Vbat <=3V and count is > 10% reset to 0% and report error difference.

Comment: Ya,this logic is helpful. But if I connect a battery which is not fully charged, it will show 100% fully charged initially in this case and cannot be detect battery capacity accurately. Isn't it?Or Am I wrong?

Comment: Depends on your initialization battery test and memory.

Comment: Because my system is battery back up system( not fully battery powered system), so often it is possible that that the culomb counting can start at any level of battery. So, my question is that can the IC automatically detect the initial capacity of the battery? Or it will take any initial level as fully charged battery?

Comment: It cannot tell the unknown capacity unless you do a load test for 1 sec. and make some historical assumptions based on experience or better a 10 minute test. Based on dV/dt and Vbat

Comment: Ok, I think after some load current passing through it, it will provide the amount of AH I have used during that time. So, how it will able to provide remaining capacity in the battery because the battery is not fully charged? So, how it will give a correct value of remaining capacity in this case?

Comment: using battery load curves you can have a lookup table to estimate from dV/dt and Vbat for 1s test  and choose % capacity from curve.

Comment: https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/inner_workings_of_a_smart_battery

Comment: Ok. It means I have to follow the battery capacity graph at different level of battery voltage. After that, if I put my load at any level of battery voltage, just deduct the AH reading during the consumption from the initial capacity which if found from battery graph at particular level. Am I Right?

Comment: that's a starting point, but calibration is essential at some point for improved accuracy and coulomb efficiency loss

Comment: Ok, I think for calibration purposes I have to do some experiments. For this the above link you have given may be useful. So, if there is any useful link with you for my program, you are welcome. If any quarry, I will let you know by the end of the day. Thanks for sharing your experience and guidance.

Comment: A battery has dynamic properties of ESR1,ESR2 C1 and C2 due to memory effects but often simplified to just Ah and ESR but C total is around 10kF per cell  Although ESR is not a great indicator of capacity it rapidly rises near 3V

Comment: Yes. Another problem is that my load is not a constant current load. So, battery is discharging in a variable C rate. So, in this case it is difficult for me to estimate the battery capacity at different voltage level as the capacity vs voltage curve is different for different C rate.

Comment: One can get all the curves and make equations with curve fitting, but a calibrated coulomb counter still takes design effort .  Batt Univ. has more details

Comment: Ok let me to study more for calibration. I will let you know after that about my quarry. Till then, thanks and welcome for any guidance regarding this in future.